$\int_a^b \sin(\theta)P_l^m(\cos\theta)\,d\theta$
I am struggling to integrate:
$$\int_a^b \sin(\theta)P_l^m(\cos\theta)\,d\theta$$
where $P_l^m$ is the associated Legendre Polynomial, $l\geq 0$, $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, and $0\leq a<b\leq \pi$
I have attempted to use the reparameterization in terms of angles as well as Gaunt's formula by using $P_1^0(\sin\theta)=\sin\theta$  (but I do not believe the conditions for it are met in this case).
I have expanded $P_l^m$ into its closed form and integrated each term, but I am hoping for a neater result as I need to compute this on a PC and would rather use as few nested sums as possible.
Edit: The problem can be changed to the following integral, if this is any easier to solve:
$$\dfrac{(-1)^m\Gamma(l+m+1)}{2^l\Gamma(l+1)}\int_a^b \sin^{m+1}\theta\,P_{l-m}^{(m,m)}(\cos\theta)d\theta$$
In the above, $P_l^{(\alpha,\beta)}(x)$ is the Jacobi polynomial. This alternative form of the integral is derived using the expansion of the associated Legendre polynomials in terms of derivatives of Legendre polynomials (linked above), and using well-known properties of Jacobi polynomials.
By using the relationship between Gegenbauer polynomials $C_n^\lambda$ and Jacobi polynomials where $\alpha=\beta$, we can further reduce this to a matter of solving for
$$\int_a^b (1-\cos^2\theta)^{m/2}\sin\theta \,C_{l-m}^{m+1/2}(\cos\theta)d\theta$$
where we suppress the coefficients that should precede this. The obvious substitution of $z=\cos\theta$ gets us to an integral that is close to this, but slightly different.

There is a closed form antiderivative in the case the sin is raised to the power of $m/2$, but in this case, especially when the bounds of the integral are fully generic, I don't think a closed form (other than the sum you obtained) is worth the effort, even if it does exist.

For $a=0$ and $b=\pi$ I suspect you could get something rather nice in terms of hypergeometrics.

The following might not be "a neater result" you are hoping for but should be helpful.
Let $t:=\cos\theta$. Then, $\frac{dt}{d\theta}=-\sin\theta$, so we have
$$\begin{align}\int_a^b \sin(\theta)P_l^m(\cos\theta)\,d\theta&=\int_{\cos a}^{\cos b} P_l^m(t)(-dt)
\\\\&=\int_{\cos b}^{\cos a} P_l^m(t)dt\end{align}$$
According to here, we have
$$\int P_{l}^{m}(t)dt=2\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{(-l)_k(l+1)_k}{\Gamma(k-m+1)k!}B_{\frac{t+1}{2}}\bigg(\frac{m+2}{2},k-\frac{m}2+1\bigg)+C\tag1$$
Since

$(N)_k=N(N+1)\cdots (N+k-1)$

$B_z(a,b)=\dfrac{z^a}{a}{}_2F_1(a,1-b;a+1;z)$ (see here)


we see that $(1)$ can be written as
$$\int P_{l}^{m}(t)dt=\frac{4(\frac{t+1}{2})^{\frac{m+2}{2}}}{m+2}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{(-1)^k\frac{(l+k)!}{(l-k)!}}{\Gamma(k-m +1)k!}{}_2F_1\bigg(\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m}2-k;\frac{m+4}{2};\frac{t+1}{2}\bigg)+C$$
Therefore, we finally get
$$\int_a^b \sin(\theta)P_l^m(\cos\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{\cos b}^{\cos a} P_l^m(t)dt$$
$$=\frac{4(\cos\frac a2)^{m+2}}{m+2}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{(-1)^k\frac{(l+k)!}{(l-k)!}}{\Gamma(k-m +1)k!}{}_2F_1\bigg(\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m}2-k;\frac{m+4}{2};\cos^2\frac a2\bigg)-\frac{4(\cos\frac b2)^{m+2}}{m+2}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{(-1)^k\frac{(l+k)!}{(l-k)!}}{\Gamma(k-m +1)k!}{}_2F_1\bigg(\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m}2-k;\frac{m+4}{2};\cos^2\frac b2\bigg)$$

Example :
If $b=\pi$, then we have
$$\int_a^{\pi} \sin(\theta)P_l^m(\cos\theta)\,d\theta=\int_{-1}^{\cos a} P_l^m(t)dt$$
$$=\frac{4(\cos\frac a2)^{m+2}}{m+2}\sum_{k=0}^{l}\frac{(-1)^k\frac{(l+k)!}{(l-k)!}}{\Gamma(k-m +1)k!}{}_2F_1\bigg(\frac{m+2}{2},\frac{m}2-k;\frac{m+4}{2};\cos^2\frac a2\bigg)$$

This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

By $x=\cos\theta$ substitution, OP's integral becomes $A_l^m=\int_{\cos b}^{\cos a}P_l^m(x)dx.$
Using the recursive formula
$$(l-m+1)P_{l+1}^m(x)=(2l+1)xP_l^m(x)-(l+m)P_{l-1}^m(x),$$
the integration by parts
$$\int xP_l^m(x)dx=\frac{x^2-1}2P_l^m(x)-\frac12\int(x^2-1)\frac d{dx}P_l^m(x)dx$$
and the derivative-recursive formula
$$(x^2-1)\frac d{dx} P_l^m(x)dx=lxP_l^m(x)-(l+m)P_{l-1}^m(x)$$
we get
$$(l-m+1)A_{l+1}^m=\frac{2l+1}{l+2}[\sin^2(b)P_l^m(\cos b)-\sin^2a P_l^m(\cos a)]+\frac{(l+m)(l-1)}{l+2}A_{l-1}^m$$

This is very interesting thank you. I'll implement this into my code to save time in evaluations!
